# How to hide widget overflow in kivy ??(Like we do in CSS)

Tags: python, kivy

**Hiding widget Overflow**

I am trying to create custom buttons in kivy.
When you click on those buttons, ripples are added as child widget with some animation and when the animation ends those ripples are removed from the parent.

I want to hide those part of ripples which are out the parent button.
There's a way to do this in CSS if you know,
by using the overflow property we can do this in CSS, but how do I do that in Kivy ??

Is there a way of doing that in kivy ??

Here's My Kivy Code:

```
Builder.load_string("""
<MyBtn@Button>:
    text: "Button"
    size: self.parent.size
    pos: self.parent.pos
    font_size: 40
    background_color: 0,0,0,0
    
    color: self.parent.btnc if self.state=="normal" else (0,0,0,1)
                
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba:
                self.parent.btnc if self.state=="normal" else (0,0,0,1)
        Line:
            width: 2.5
            rounded_rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height, self.height*0.4
        Color:
            rgba:
                (0,0,0,1) if self.state=="normal" else self.parent.btnc
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: [self.height*0.4]



<MainScreen>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0.05,0.05,0.05,1)
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    
    CustomBtn:
        size: 250, 90
        pos: 0, 1000
        center_x: root.center_x
        btnc: (1,0,0,1)
        
        MyBtn:
    
    CustomBtn:
        size: 250, 90
        pos: 0, 800
        center_x: root.center_x
        btnc: (1,1,0,1)
        
        MyBtn:
            
    CustomBtn:
        size: 250, 90
        pos: 0, 600
        center_x: root.center_x
        btnc: (0,1,0,1)
        
        MyBtn:
            
    CustomBtn:
        size: 250, 90
        pos: 0, 400
        center_x: root.center_x
        btnc: (0,1,1,1)
        
        MyBtn:
""")
```

Here's My Python Code:

```
class CustomBtn(Widget):
    btnc = ListProperty([1,1,1,1]) # For Btn color
    alpha = NumericProperty(0.3)
    
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        super(CustomBtn,self).on_touch_down(touch)
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            ripple = Widget()
            ripple.size = 30,30
            ripple.center = touch.pos
            ripple.bind(size=self.update_canvas)
            
            with ripple.canvas.before:
                Color(self.btnc[0],self.btnc[1],self.btnc[2],self.alpha)
                Ellipse(size=ripple.size,
                                pos=ripple.pos)
            
            anim = Animation(size=(600,600),    
                            center=touch.pos, 
                            opacity=0, d=1)
            
            anim.bind(on_complete=self.remove)
            
            self.add_widget(ripple)
            anim.start(ripple)
            
    # Removes widget after the animation completes
    def remove(self, anim, widget):
        self.remove_widget(widget)
    
    # Updates Ripple's Canvas on size change of the ripple
    def update_canvas(self, ripple, val):
        ripple.canvas.before.clear()
        
        with ripple.canvas.before:
            Color(self.btnc[0],self.btnc[1],self.btnc[2],self.alpha)
            Ellipse(size=val,pos=ripple.pos)

        

class MainScreen(Widget):
    pass
    
runTouchApp(MainScreen())
```

Comment: You might want [TouchRippleButtonBehavior](https://kivy.org/doc/master/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.touchripple.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [stencil instructions](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.graphics.stencil_instructions.html), or the [StencilView](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.stencilview.html) widget.